# Как вывести запросом значения одного столбца в строку сгруппировав по другому столбцу?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Как из этой таблицы:

```
employer_name           | profession_name
----------------------------------------
Рога и копыта             Шлифовальщик
Рога и копыта             Слесарь
Рога и копыта             Фрезеровщик
ГАЗ                       Шлифовальщик
ГАЗ                       Шлифовальщик
Станкостроительный завод  Слесарь
Станкостроительный завод  Слесарь
Станкостроительный завод  Кровельщик
Станкостроительный завод  Слесарь
Станкостроительный завод  Автоводитель
КИНАП                     Автоводитель
КИНАП                     Счетовод
КИНАП                     Автоводитель
КРАЗ                      Кровельщик
п\я 12687-у               Кровельщик
п\я 12687-у               Кровельщик
```

получить более удобную таблицу, например, чтобы в столбце было 'Рога и копыта' а по строкам соответствующее ему `profession_name`?

Можно ли сделать с помощью циклов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [string_agg()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11.1/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT employer_name, string_agg(profession_name, ',') as profession_list
FROM table_name
GROUP BY employer_name;
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!, хороший вариант.